# What is the SQL equivalent to pandas 'transform'?

Tags: mysql, sql, pandas, psql

Suppose you have the following SQL table:

```
  A  B  C  
  2  1  4       
  3  4  5     
  3  1  1    
  1  4  0       
  5  0  1
```

And you want to add/show a column containing the mean (or any other aggregate function) of column A for each distinct value of column B. You want to keep all columns. So the result would look like this:

```
  A  B  C    avg(A)|B
  2  1  4       2.5
  3  4  5       2.0
  3  1  1       2.5
  1  4  0       2.0
  5  0  1       5.0
```

The best way to do it in pandas, as far as I know, would be:

```
>>> df['avg(A)|B'] = df.groupby('B')['A'].transform('mean')
>>> df
   A  B  C  avg(A)|B
0  2  1  4       2.5
1  3  4  5       2.0
2  3  1  1       2.5
3  1  4  0       2.0
4  5  0  1       5.0
```

How would you do it in SQL? Can one avoid using a JOIN?

Comment: Why would you avoid join? Even in background pandas does join :)

Comment: @WoodChopper Aren't FuzzyTree's queries using a subquery or a window function more efficient than doing a join?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can join to a derived table that contains the aggregate value for each grouping of b

```
select * from mytable t1
join (
    select avg(a), b
    from mytable
    group by b
) t2 on t2.b = t1.b
```

or using a subquery

```
select *, (select avg(a) from mytable t2 where t2.b = t1.b)
from mytable t1
```

the question is tagged both mysql and psql, so I'm not sure which db you're using. But on postgres you can use window functions

```
select *, avg(a) over (partition by b) 
from mytable
```

Comment: First, I forgot to say that I was trying to avoid a join, sorry. Is it possible? On another issue, why do you need the 'distinct'? I want to considerer all values of A (unique and not unique) for each value of B.

Comment: @drake mysql doesn't support window functions, so I don't think there's a way to do it w/o a subquery or join