# How Can I optimise my code further using Pandas for the required Problem

Tags: python, pandas

i have created a following dataset

```
dataset1 = { 'srid':[1,2,3,1,5],
            'custid':[11,12,43,12,34],
            'orderdate':["1/2/2019","1/2/2019","2/2/2019","1/2/2019","1/2/2019"],
            'Rev':[100,101,102,103,17]
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dataset1)
```

I have to mark every sales representative as :
Excellent(where his total revenue for a day is 1.5 times or greater than average revenue of
all sales representative for that day)
Good (where his total revenue for a day is less than 1.5 times and greater than equal to 1.1
times average revenue of all sales representative for that day)
Average (where his total revenue for a day is less than 1.1 times and greater than equal
to 0.9 times the average revenue of all sales representative for that day)
Poor (where his total revenue for a day is less than 0.9 times the average revenue of all
sales representative for that day) for every date present in ‘Dataset 1’
Output Dataset: Sales Representative ID,Order Date, Marking

what i tried is:

```
g=df.groupby(df['orderdate'])
ans={}
for od,od_df in g:
   # print(od)
    ans[od]=list()
    x=od_df["Rev"].mean()
    s=set(od_df["srid"].tolist())
    for i in s:
        p=od_df[od_df["srid"]==i]["Rev"].sum()
        val = p/x
        if val>=1.5:
            ans[od].append([i,od,"Excellent"])
        elif 1.1<=val<1.5:
            ans[od].append([i,od,"good"])
        elif 0.9<=val<1.1:
            ans[od].append([i,od,"avg"])
        else:
            ans[od].append([i,od,"poor"])
```

But that is alot to write and  will take more time on big dataset how can i optimise it further

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Comment: output:Sales Representative ID,Order Date, Marking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a column to be calculated and 'apply' to the result

```
df1['mean'] = df1.loc[:,['orderdate','Rev']].groupby('orderdate').transform('mean')
df1['Representative'] = df1['Rev']/df1['mean']

def rep(x):
    if x >= 1.5:
        return 'Excellent'
    elif 1.1<=x<1.5:
        return 'good'
    elif 0.9<=x<1.1:
        return 'avg'
    else:
        return 'poor'

df1['Marking'] = df1['Representative'].apply(rep)
df1
    srid    custid  orderdate   Rev mean    Representative  Marking
0   1   11  1/2/2019    100 80.25   1.246106    good
1   2   12  1/2/2019    101 80.25   1.258567    good
2   3   43  2/2/2019    102 102.00  1.000000    avg
3   1   12  1/2/2019    103 80.25   1.283489    good
4   5   34  1/2/2019    17  80.25   0.211838    poor
```

Comment: Thanks that is really helpful .. can you suggest some good resources to learn some writing complex queries using groupby and trasform

Comment: I don't know of any site that explains it in detail either, but I just looked it up and found [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33730092/what-is-the-sql-equivalent-to-pandas-transform), [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22105452/what-is-the-equivalent-of-sql-group-by-having-on-pandas), [TDS](https://towardsdatascience.com/group-by-in-pandas-and-sql-94777ce48658), etc.

Answer (score 2):

I can't really test the speed of the implementation in comparison to yours as for 5 values it measures the overhead more than anything else. However bare loops tend to be rather inefficient in pandas. You can get the relative difference to the mean like this:

```
In [15]: df.groupby('orderdate').apply(lambda _df: _df['Rev'] / _df['Rev'].mean())                                                                                                                         
Out[15]: 
orderdate   
1/2/2019   0    1.2461
           1    1.2586
           3    1.2835
           4    0.2118
2/2/2019   2    1.0000
Name: Rev, dtype: float64
```

and use `pd.cut` to transform it to an ordinal scale

```
In [28]: df['RevMark'] = pd.cut(df.groupby('orderdate').apply(lambda _df: _df['Rev'] / _df['Rev'].mean()).sort_index(level=1).values, [0,0.9,1.1,1.5,np.inf], labels=['poor', 'avg', 'good', 'excellent']) 

In [29]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[29]: 
   srid  custid orderdate  Rev RevMark
0     1      11  1/2/2019  100    good
1     2      12  1/2/2019  101    good
2     3      43  2/2/2019  102     avg
3     1      12  1/2/2019  103    good
4     5      34  1/2/2019   17    poor
```

The `sort_index` is necessary because after the grouping the values are ordered by date and thus the association would be wrong. The second argument of `cut` is the borders of your desired intervals and the labels are What you call Marks.

In terms of time you would need to measure that on a suffiently large sample yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like that

```
list_df = []
for date in df.orderdate.unique():
    df_cur = df[df.orderdate==date]
    mean = df_cur.rev.Mean()
    def get_rank(rev):
        if rev > 1.5*mean:
           return "Good"
        elif rev .......
    df_cur["Ranking"]=df_cur.rev.apply(get_rank)
    list_df.append(df_cur)
df_final = pd.concat(list_df)
```

I mean, you need to tweak it, but I think it should work

For each date, I get the following dataframe, and then I get the ranking for the day. In the end, I merge all the dataframes to get all the dates.

Comment: Why are you defining a function in a loop? Why call `apply` in a loop when it applies to a whole Series?

Comment: The rank and the ranking depend on the date, so the function that gives the rank changes with everydate. For each date, I get the following dataframe, and then I get the ranking for the day. In the end, I merge all the dataframes to get all the dates.